# Composer - skipping package from private repo

Tags: composer-php

We have a package from a private repo that we don't wish to be accessed by everyone. Problem is, when others run `composer install` it will inevitably fail.

To save us sharing keys or telling other developers to comment this line out every time, is there a way to tell composer to safely skip this package?

Just so you know this is a module required in the live environment so `require-dev` will not work in this case.

Comment: If it is a required package, why should `composer` not fail when it cannot install it?

Comment: Good point,  does composer have a non required section?

Comment: How about https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#suggest?